How to get a non-exhaustive GROUP BY to not give random values
I am still somewhat new to SQL, so please bear with me.
Fundamentally what I want to do is the following, I have two tables:
mysql\> SELECT * FROM product_table;
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| id | product_name              | category_array                       |
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | Hike boots - Breathable M | \["12341", "21342", "31243"\]          |
|  2 | Tent throwable - XL       | \["1239999", "21342", "1239999"\]      |
|  3 | Running boots pegasus - S | \[ "12341",  "1239999", "31243"\]      |
|  4 | Light Xtra bright - Wide  | \["12399999", "21342", "41234"\]       |
|  5 | Medical kit               | \["12399999", "12388888", "12377777"\] |
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+

mysql\> SELECT * FROM category_table;
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | category_name | category_id |
+----+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | Clothing      | 12341       |
|  2 | Camping       | 21342       |
|  3 | Sport         | 31243       |
|  4 | Accessories   | 41234       |
+----+---------------+-------------+

I want to combine these into a single table, like this :
mysql> SELECT * FROM product_table_combined;
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+
| id | product_name              | category_array                       | category |
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | Hike boots - Breathable M | ["12341", "21342", "31243"]          | Clothing |
|  2 | Tent throwable - XL       | ["1239999", "21342", "1239999"]      | Camping  |
|  3 | Running boots pegasus - S | [ "12341",  "1239999", "31243"]      | Clothing |
|  4 | Light Xtra bright - Wide  | ["12399999", "21342", "41234"]       | Camping  |
|  5 | Medical kit               | ["12399999", "12388888", "12377777"] | NULL     |
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------+

Thus when the join happens I only the row to be added for the category that appears first in category_array or a NULL if it is not present in category_array. (I also want a version that appears last, but I hope that the SQL queries will be similar)

I have tried many things to try and make this happen, the closest that I have gotten is creating a temporary table, which has an additional column index_found specifying how soon in category_array it was found.
Using this command:
INSERT INTO temp_product_table_combined(product_name, category_array, category, index_found)

SELECT product.product_name, product.category_array, ANY_VALUE(category.category_name), MIN(REGEXP_INSTR(product.category_array, category.category_id)) 

FROM product_table AS product 
LEFT JOIN category_table AS category ON product.category_array LIKE CONCAT('%', category.category_id, '%')
GROUP BY 
    product.product_name, product.category_array

Which gives almost the correct behaviour except that it gets a random value for the column of category.
mysql\> SELECT \* FROM temp_product_table_combined;
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | product_name              | category_array                       | category    | index_found |
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | Hike boots - Breathable M | \["12341", "21342", "31243"\]          | Sport       |           3 |
|  2 | Tent throwable - XL       | \["1239999", "21342", "1239999"\]      | Camping     |          14 |
|  3 | Running boots pegasus - S | \[ "12341",  "1239999", "31243"\]      | Sport       |           4 |
|  4 | Light Xtra bright - Wide  | \["12399999", "21342", "41234"\]       | Accessories |          15 |
|  5 | Medical kit               | \["12399999", "12388888", "12377777"\] | NULL        |        NULL |
+----+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+

The problem lies with the necessity of ANY_VALUE. If I leave it out (which if allowed, should I believe give the correct table). I get the error message:
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'playground.category.category_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.
I have tried doing a global disable of only_full_group_by mode and removing the ANY_VALUE, but it still gives this behaviour.

Hi - this seems to be a really good example of why holding values in an array (rather than using a proper relational model) is a bad idea - but I'm guessing that's not something you can change? Anyway, while your question has a lot of example tables, you don't seem to have included one that shows the actual result you want, based on your source data (apologies if I've missed it) - please can you add this table to your question? Thanks

I added the desired table to my post, and no this is not something I can change. I suppose I can do some ugly logic with PHP on the back-end though...

welcome to terrible database design.  i would renormalize that if at all possible.

Given that MySQL doesn't support arrays (as far as I know) what's the datatype for the category_array column? Is it just a text/char column that's been populated with a string that looks like an array?

Yes, it is a VARCHAR:(

Urgh, I guess you could use the JSON_TABLE function to parse it.

I don't understand why people are giving negative voting for this query. This is a beautiful query for learning & practice ... I really like it

If you only want to match the first category in the array, use a LIKE pattern that matches the [" at the beginning:
ON product.category_array LIKE CONCAT('[":', category.category_id, '"%')

You could also use a JSON function to extract the first category from the array:
ON category.category_id = product.category_array->>"$[0]"


The problem is I have no certainty as to the precise layout of category_array, It could vary in production

Why would it vary? How much can it vary? It's already a bad design to put a list in one field, instead of normalizing. But why would the layout be different?

You could use JSON_TABLE() to extract the category ids from the array to separate rows.
WITH product_categories (p_id, category_name, rn) AS (
    SELECT p.id, c.category_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY categories.ord) AS rn
    FROM product_table p
    CROSS JOIN
        JSON_TABLE(
            p.category_array,
            '$[*]' COLUMNS (cat_id INT PATH '$', ord FOR ORDINALITY)
        ) categories
    INNER JOIN category_table c ON categories.cat_id = c.category_id
)
SELECT p.id, p.product_name, p.category_array, pc.category_name
FROM product_table p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc
    ON p.id = pc.p_id AND pc.rn = 1;

Output:



id
product_name
category_array
category_name




1
Hike boots - Breathable M
["12341", "21342", "31243"]
Clothing


2
Tent throwable - XL
["1239999", "21342", "1239999"]
Camping


3
Running boots pegasus - S
["12341", "1239999", "31243"]
Clothing


4
Light Xtra bright - Wide
["12399999", "21342", "41234"]
Camping


5
Medical kit
["12399999", "12388888", "12377777"]
null



You can change this query to display the last category, instead of the first, by changing the direction of the ORDER BY in the OVER clause for the ROW_NUMBER() window function.
Output:



id
product_name
category_array
category_name




1
Hike boots - Breathable M
["12341", "21342", "31243"]
Sport


2
Tent throwable - XL
["1239999", "21342", "1239999"]
Camping


3
Running boots pegasus - S
["12341", "1239999", "31243"]
Sport


4
Light Xtra bright - Wide
["12399999", "21342", "41234"]
Accessories


5
Medical kit
["12399999", "12388888", "12377777"]
null



Here's a db<>fiddle.

Yes, CORSS JOIN with respect to product.category_array & category_table.category_id is best way to found the accurate table. That also resolve my first answer limitation. 
After doing the CORSS JOIN, we need to filter out maximum non-zero value of category_id index in category_array column.
This is MySQL query as follows:
WITH T AS (
    SELECT p.*,
    c.category_name,
    REGEXP_INSTR(p.category_array, c.category_id, 1) as cNAME_index

    FROM product_table p
    CROSS JOIN category_table c 
), T1 AS (
    Select *, 
        max(CASE 
                WHEN cNAME_index > 0 
                    THEN cNAME_index 
            END) over (partition by id) as max_non_zero_cNAME_index
        
    from T
)
select id,
    product_name, 
    category_array,
    category_name
from 
-- First Table: when category_id index is not NULL
T1 WHERE (max_non_zero_cNAME_index > 0 AND cNAME_index = max_non_zero_cNAME_index)
UNION 
-- Second Table: when category_id index is NULL
(   select id,
        product_name, 
        category_array,
        NULL as category_name
    from T1
    where  (max_non_zero_cNAME_index IS NULL)
    GROUP BY id, product_name, category_array
)

Output:

Result: db<>fiddle

Older query response: https://dbfiddle.uk/7-Jl4ARB (reference for me)
